# Why did Dick Stensland laugh in this segment?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

One Christmas night in *L.A Confidential* (1997), Officer Bud White departs from a bar and notices a
woman with a bandaged nose in the vicinity of a car. Approaching the vehicle,
Bud confronts Buzz, a former cop seated in the driver's position. After
conducting a thorough search and finding a firearm, Bud inquires about
the woman's well-being. Receiving confirmation that she is unharmed,
Bud confiscates the bullets from Buzz's gun and joins with
Dick Stensland:

> Dick Stensland: What's going on?
>
> Bud White: You know him?
>
> Dick Stensland: Yeah, I've seen him around. He used to be a cop.
>
> *(Dick Stensland laughs)*

Why did Dick Stensland laugh in this scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/ellay-confidential_early.html):

> For an odd moment, Stensland and Meeks lock eyes.
>
> Dick Stensland: Yeah, he used to be a cop.

**This is just sarcasm**. Capt. Dudley Smith even says that Buzz Meeks is a disgrace as a police officer. Buzz lost his badge and respect, he has no "rights" and won't be considered by former colleagues as "one of them".